# How can I prove it?!

Tags: probability

let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent RV with the same distribution.
Prove that:
$$P\left(|X-Y|\le 2\right)\le 3P\left(|X-Y|\le 1\right)$$
I was wondering if you help me.

Comment: I have tried by using integration but it didnt give any result :(

Comment: 4/8≦3*2/4 mensurating area